# How do I build a FastAI docker image on raspberry pi?

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi, arm, fast-ai

I have a Raspberry Pi that can effectively run a simple FastAI vision model natively without any issues. However, my problems come when I try to Dockerize it and serve it as a container behind a proxy. I can't seem to build a Docker image that will work.

Whenever I run docker-compose I just get an error in the logs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 2, in <module>
    import fastai.vision as fastai

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/vision/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .. import basics

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/basics.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .basic_train import *

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/basic_train.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .torch_core import *

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/torch_core.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .imports.torch import *

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/imports/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .torch import *

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/imports/torch.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch, torch.nn.functional as F

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 190, in <module>
    from torch._C import *

ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
```

This is the current dockerfile I'm using.

```
FROM python:3.7.10-stretch

WORKDIR /app

ADD . .

RUN useradd fastai-user

RUN apt update

RUN apt upgrade -y

RUN cp libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6

RUN apt install -y libopenblas-dev libblas-dev m4 cmake cython python3-dev python3-yaml python3-setuptools python3-wheel

RUN apt install -y libatlas3-base

RUN pip install numpy

RUN pip install Pillow==8.1.2

RUN pip install -r requirements-pi-freeze.txt

RUN pip install torch-*.whl

RUN pip install torchvision*.whl

RUN pip install fastai==1.0.57 --no-deps
```

I've tried adding RUN apt install gcc6.0 and more but I haven't been able to get it to work either and I just end up with the same import error under `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6` not found error. So I manually added that file in the dockerfile folder (along with torch-1.7.0a0-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl and torchvision-0.8.0a0+45f960c-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl).

Here is the requirements-pi-freeze.txt file too.

```
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
Bottleneck==1.3.2
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
cycler==0.10.0
dataclasses==0.6
fastprogress==1.0.0
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
future==0.18.2
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
kiwisolver==1.3.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.3.4
numexpr==2.7.3
nvidia-ml-py3==7.352.0
packaging==20.9
pandas==1.2.3
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
PyYAML==5.4.1
requests==2.25.1
scipy==1.6.1
spacy==2.0.18
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.26.4
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Comment: What OS are you running on the RPi? Your Docker uses Debian, but maybe if you are using Raspbian natively, there is something different.

Comment: I'm using Raspbian however I was able to get other flask servers to run on the `FROM python:3.7.10-stretch` image without any issues.

Comment: Alright. Could you find out what version of glibc Stretch uses? Maybe your code needs 2.28, but Stretch includes a different version.

Comment: (I am no expert here, but I wonder if I would try installing the right things, rather than copying in binary objects like `libstdc++.so.6`. It is interesting you get a failure when you bring the container up - I would have expected it to fail when you build the image).

Comment: Out of interest, does this fail only on a RPi, and works on a desktop computer? (i.e. does one need an RPi to get this to fail?)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I realized the pytorch library that I was getting the arm source from requires rebulding c++ so I've been doing that. https://github.com/ljk53/pytorch-rpi. However I'm still running into issues building it within the container `FAILED: test_api/CMakeFiles/test_api.dir/modules.cpp.o ...  c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)`. And this only fails when trying to containerize it on the Pi. It works on the host Raspbian image just fine. I'll report back after looking into a different image, but it takes a few hours to build each time.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by completely rebuilding the docker image from `arm32v7/python:3.7.10-buster` The image was slightly larger than 3.7.10-stretch but any space savings were completely overshadowed by the size of rebuilding the c++ libraries for pytorch on arm from scratch (Final image size wound up around 6.5 gbs. This can probably be optimized.)

Here was my final dockerfile for building a fastai flask python server from scratch.

```
FROM arm32v7/python:3.7.10-buster

WORKDIR /app

ADD . .

RUN useradd fastai-user

RUN apt update

RUN apt upgrade -y

RUN apt install -y sudo git

ENV LIBTORCH_VARIANT=armv7l-cxx11-abi-shared-without-deps

RUN ./pytorch-rpi/build_libtorch.sh

RUN pip install numpy

RUN pip install Pillow==8.1.2

RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

RUN apt install -y gfortran

RUN pip install scipy==1.6.1

RUN pip install -r requirements-pi-freeze.txt

RUN pip install torch-*.whl

RUN pip install torchvision*.whl

RUN pip install fastai==1.0.57 --no-deps

CMD ["python", "server.py"]
```

Comment: I have a similar issue on Raspberry Pi 3B+. I tried your solution and it didn't work. Wonderful that you are able o get FastAI on a Pi.